# Are meta 4 Heavy Neuts as good as Tech 2 Heavy Neuts?

Tags: eve-online

There are quite a few item types where the meta 4 variant is as good as the Tech 2 variant, often the meta 4 is even easier to fit.

I did compare the Heavy Energy Neutralizers and on first glance the "Heavy Unstable Power Fluctuator I" seems to be identical in effectiveness to the "Heavy Energy Neutralizer II" while being easier to fit. But then I noticed one difference in Pyfa in an obscure parameter: The parameter `entityCapacitorLevelModifierSmall` is -97.95% for the meta 4 Neut and -78.04% for the Tech 2 Neut.

Does this parameter make any difference, and if it does what exactly does it affect? Are the meta 4 Neuts equivalent to T2 Neuts in performance, or is there a difference?

Answer (score 2):

You have found one of the oddities of EVE.

Sometimes the T2 is just worst then the meta 4. In many of these cases, the meta 4 is more expensive, but in this case the meta 4 is 10x cheaper.

[This forum post](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=306344) has a list of cases where the meta 4 is better then the T2.

Comment: BTW that is over 5 years old. Thanks to rebalancing, much of this may no longer be true.